# Why do I see applications with high numbers of page faults when I have a lot of memory available?

Tags: windows, pagefile

I've noticed that some applications (often games) have a very high number of page faults; for example, Diablo III can get into the range of 2 million within 30 minutes of play.

Why is this? Does something other than the OS needing a page that isn't in physical memory cause a page fault? Why am I seeing 2 million page faults when I have 3-4 GB of RAM free, shouldn't the operating system be able to keep everything paged in?

Comment: It could be a memory mapped file. It's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Also, you get a page fault each time a new block of virtual memory is allocated.  In particular this means you get at least one page fault for every new thread, when the stack is allocated.  So if a program either creates lots of short-lived threads or allocates and releases memory often, you'll get a high page fault count.